# How to make pass a test case which use enzyme shallow with contains when a React component has an event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I cannot make pass a test which use .contain when the react component has an event handler. Examples:

Foo.js

---

```
 const Foo = React.createClass({
      render () {
        return (
          <p onClick={() => {}}>I am not a very smart component...</p>
        )
      }
    })
 export default Foo
```

### Foo.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import Foo from './Foo'

describe('<Foo />', () => {
  it('renders a <p> with a static text', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper.contains(<p>I am not a very smart component...</p>)).toBe(true)
  })
```

The console result when using `.debug()` is

```
<p onClick={[Function]}>
    I am not a very smart component...
</p>
```

please note `onClick={[Function]}`

I tried to change my test case to:

```
describe('<Foo />', () => {
  it('renders a <p> with a static text', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper.contains(<p onClick={() => {}}>I am not a very smart component...</p>)).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

but the test still does not pass.

I would like to know:

- How to fix it and make the test pass using `shallow` and `.contain` and a brief explanation why my current approach does not work.

Comment: pass onClick as props

Comment: @OluwafemiSule please add an example in your answer :) Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component instances are checked for props and their values.
An instance without a click handler differs from that having one.

> .contains(nodeOrNodes) => Boolean
>
> Returns whether or not all given react elements match elements in the render tree. It will determine if an element in the wrapper matches the expected element **by checking if the expected element has the same props as the wrapper's element and share the same values**.

Also instances having different handlers are different.

We can pass the click handler as prop to `Foo` component.

```
import React from 'react'


class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.props.onClick}>I am not a very smart component...</p>
    )
  }
}

export default Foo
```

By passing your handler as props, you can inject a mock function.

This way you can be sure that prop value passed down as click handler is the mock function.

```
describe('<Foo />', () => {

  it('renders a <p> with a static text', () => {
    const fn = () => {};
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo onClick={fn} />);

    expect(wrapper.contains(
        <p onClick={fn}>I am not a very smart component...</p>
    )).to.be(true);

  });

});
```